# vline im:recv event error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'log' of undefined in vline.js

Tags: javascript, vline

When receiving a vLine im, I experience an uncaught TypeError.

Set up the event handler:

this.client_.on('recv:im', this.onMessageRecv, this);

onMessageRecv is:

```
function (aEvent) {
      var msg = event.message;
      var sender = msg.getSender();

      this.displayError(sender.getDisplayName(),
                        sender.getThumbnailUrl(),
                        msg.getBody());
}
```

(displayError is merely calling alert)

Not sure if this is helpful or not, but here is a screengrab of the debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkXrT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the event argument with the name `aEvent` and then attempting to reference it as `event.message` instead of `aEvent.message`.